# What are the most useful TextMate bundles or plugins for Rails development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, textmate

I'm compiling a list of the most useful bundles and plugins for TextMate which are helpful for using while developing with Rails.

I have two which I use religiously:

- [Project Plus](http://ciaranwal.sh/2008/08/05/textmate-plug-in-projectplus)
- [Zen Coding](http://code.google.com/p/zen-coding/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- [RubyAmp](http://tim.theenchanter.com/2008/03/rubyamp-released-out-into-wild.html)
- [Git](http://tim.theenchanter.com/2008/03/git-bundle-111-released.html)
- [Haml](http://bjhess.com/blog/2007/05/31/installing-haml-bundle-for-textmate/)

Answer (score 3):

Find in Project in TextMate is slow in a large project. Try "Ack In Project Bundle" http://github.com/protocool/ack-tmbundle

Answer (score 1):

I get a lot of mileage out of the Haml and Sass bundles.

Answer (score 1):

[Listed under TextMate Bundles:](http://frozenplague.net/2009/08/snow-leopard-rubyrails-developer-setup/)

- Cucumber
- Javascript Tools (ever wanted warnings / errors when saving file?)
- Ruby on Rails by the effervescent Dr Nic (disclaimer: he's my boss)
- Ruby HAML
- RubyAMP

Not listed:

- RSpec
- Javascript jQuery